# Tweet emotion prediction using CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a built a CNN model for tweet emotion detection and the final step is as follows:

```
tweets_emotion = model.predict(val_tweets, verbose= 0)
```

which gave me predicted output like this

```
array([[3.1052819e-01, 2.7634043e-01, 1.6270137e-03, 7.7674150e-01],
       [5.0230421e-02, 7.7430069e-01, 7.7313791e-09, 2.0278792e-01],
       [9.9952579e-01, 1.3450404e-03, 5.8804121e-20, 3.2991991e-07],
       ...,
       [3.9727339e-01, 2.8888196e-01, 1.9649005e-02, 2.1239746e-01],
       [1.2528910e-01, 3.2127723e-01, 3.2503495e-03, 5.5401272e-01],
       [5.8543805e-02, 4.5720499e-05, 2.9060062e-12, 9.3766922e-01]],
      dtype=float32)
```

my actual output should look like this:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Is there a way to convert my predicted output (tweets_emotion) to look like the output that I expected?

Comment: Your output does not look right, i.e. it does not look like the output of a softmax; each array should add up to 1.0, which is not the case here. Please show your actual model.

Comment: I used sigmoid activation here.

Comment: Sigmoid does not make sense in single-label multi-class settings with one-hot encoded labels, as your setting seems to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 6 predictions example you show here:

```
import numpy as np

tweets_emotion = np.array([[3.1052819e-01, 2.7634043e-01, 1.6270137e-03, 7.7674150e-01],
                           [5.0230421e-02, 7.7430069e-01, 7.7313791e-09, 2.0278792e-01],
                           [9.9952579e-01, 1.3450404e-03, 5.8804121e-20, 3.2991991e-07],
                           [3.9727339e-01, 2.8888196e-01, 1.9649005e-02, 2.1239746e-01],
                           [1.2528910e-01, 3.2127723e-01, 3.2503495e-03, 5.5401272e-01],
                           [5.8543805e-02, 4.5720499e-05, 2.9060062e-12, 9.3766922e-01]])

tweets_emotion_class = np.argmax(tweets_emotion, axis=1)
tweets_emotion_class
# array([3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3])
```

You should be able to verify by simple visual inspection that indeed, the maximum values of each array element are the ones shown in `tweets_emotion_class`.

Irrelevant to your issue but, as mentioned in the comments, `sigmoid` activation for the last network layer does not make sense in single-label multi-class settings with one-hot encoded labels, as your setting seems to be - you should change it to `softmax`.